# Как на php создать дубли страниц по другим урл?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Имеется к примеру страничка:
https://domain.com/category/sale/f345654/f5675673/356777/

Нужно, чтобы содержимое этой страницы отобрадалось к примеру и на:

https://domain.com/category/qwerty/

В какую сторону смотреть?)

Спасибо!

Comment: не проще через htaccess RewriteRule это сделать? или нужно именно спарсить?

Comment: парсить не нужно, нужно просто переписать урл, а как это сделать через  htaccess RewriteRule?